# Unable to force checks in icinga

Tags: icinga

On the Icinga instance I look after some of the service checks aren't running on the schedule they should be.  Moreover when I try to schedule a manual check I get the error message

`Logger "4294967296" has not been configured.`

The log file contains the folowing.

[Thu Jun 11 19:35:38 2015] [debug] Setting up console for instance default  (Cronks_System_CommandSenderModel::getConsoleInstance(), line 79)

[Thu Jun 11 19:35:38 2015] [debug] Submitting command SCHEDULE_FORCED_SVC_CHECK to {"host":"  test.example.net","service":"HTTP","instance":"default"} (Cronks_System_CommandSenderModel::dispatchCommands(), line 69)

[Thu Jun 11 19:35:38 2015] [info] Sending command failed Logger "4294967296" has not been configured.

Does anyone have any idea what this issue is?

Comment: You shouldn't guess nor speak that harsh - it doesn't help anyone (maybe you and your anger, but not long enough). We've seen the issue and are discussing it offline (it is vacation time as well). In terms of packages - join the team, add your feedback directly and be a hero for anyone else gaving the same issue.

Comment: I've installed the classic UI in standalone mode so that I have a usable icinga instance

Comment: @dnsmichi I have deleted my comment. Still it is an horrible idea to have only the latest version in the repo is very bad. Icingaweb is staying only until icingaweb2 is stable enough for our needs, I would have happily rolled back and forgot about this issue

Comment: @Bruno9779 I don't think this is the right place to discuss this further. Contact the team, or create a referencing issue. https://www.icinga.org/community/get-involved/

Answer (score 0):

Seems someone else has reported a bug with a similar error to their dev.
https://dev.icinga.org/issues/9323

Have you tried restarting syslog and do the permissions appear to be ok?

Comment: Thanks for that bug report. I've tried restarting icinga, ido2db & the entire machine but none of those attempts worked.  Permissions of what?

Comment: Im not certain what it might be, I would grep for 4294967296 inside the xml/conf to see if that is configured somewhere and check the permissions on that.

Comment: It appears in app/modules/AppKit/lib/logging/AppKitLogger.class.php defined as const COMMAND = 4294967296;  However, it isn't used anywhere else in that file, and greping for COMMAND has the predictable result.